# Expo React native crashing on IOS after AbortController abort call

Tags: react-native, expo, fetch, abortcontroller

I am using expo react native `fech` request:

```
                        const controller = new AbortController();
                        const { signal } = controller;
                        fetch('xxxxxxxxx/system/sleep3000ms', { signal }) 
                            .then(async r => {
                                const rr = await r.json(); 
                                console.log(rr);
                            }) 
                            .catch(console.error);

                        setTimeout(() => { 
                            console.log('abort');
                            controller.abort();
                        }, 1000);
```

Problem is that every time when `controller.abort()` is called the app crash without any error.

This problem is not on development env, but **only in expo published app** and on **IOS device**.

Canceling unnecessary requests is core function.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use polyfill https://github.com/mo/abortcontroller-polyfill

```js
npm install --save abortcontroller-polyfill
```

If you're using webpack or similar, you then import it early in your client entrypoint .js file using

```js
import 'abortcontroller-polyfill/dist/polyfill-patch-fetch';
```

---

Or update to the latest Expo SDK https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/22064